# Get user current and exact location using GPS

Tags: android, gps

For my new app, I need to get user location using GPS. To do so, I am using `fusedLocationProviderApi.getLastLocation`. Most of the time I am getting `null`. 
But then I realized that all the APIs are intended to get notified on Location changed. But I want to take current exact location of user (consider user not moving) in the app. 
How do I get the Location object so that I don't get `null` each time.

Comment: Yeah, I agree about the brief idea about getting location. But my point is that for the above mentioned implementation, onLocationChanged would be called on every change in location, Not just get location of standing user. Or I got it completely wrong?

Comment: can you please update your locationProvider also in question.

Comment: `onLocationChanged()` will fire once the location has been resolved. The user doesn't need to physically move.

Comment: Mike M. Thanks for the insight :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in `OnCreate()` method to get location

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
      makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try out the solution :)

Comment: If you found it help full up vote or accept the answer

Comment: Accepted your solution. thanks :)